# How to create a Bootstrap 4 card where some element overflows the card or offset from normal flow

Tags: bootstrap-4

Many examples of Bootstrap cards where content is all inside the card is arrange linearly.  How does one add an element that overflows the card?

Here is a picture of what I am looking for:

[image]

How do I place a rotated div on to the top of the card?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add a element and use `position:absolute` in collaboration with `transform:rotate` to get the badge over the card.
Use `text-center` for where you want the text to be centered.

```css
body {
  padding:50px; /* this is just to get some space, unneccessary for the badge implementation itself */
}

.card {
  position:relative;
}
  
.card .card-badge {
  position:absolute;
  top:-10px;
  left:-30px;
  padding:5px;
  background:blue;
  color:white;
  transform:rotate(-20deg);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="https://dummyimage.com/286x180" alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-body text-center">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
  <div class="card-badge">Strawberries</div>
</div>
```